# Stash and Categories

Tags: categories, stash, parse-order

Is it possible to set the category id in a channel entries tag based on the last segment or by another method so that I don't have to create multiple templates?

I'm trying to get this template to fly.

```
{embed="_layouts/index"}

{exp:stash:append name="listings"}
        <div class="widget">
            <div class="whead"><h6>Listings</h6></div>
            <div class="shownpars">
                <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" class="dTable">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>Name<span class="sorting" style="display: block;"></span></th>
                            <th>Location</th>
                            <th>Phone</th>
                            <th>Email</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        {exp:channel:entries channel="members" category="{category_id}" status="Open" limit="100" disable="category_fields|member_data|pagination|trackbacks" dynamic="no"}
                        <tr>
                            <td>{title}</td>
                            <td>{member_location}</td>
                            <td>{member_phone}</td>
                            <td class="center">{member_email}</td>
                        </tr>
                        {/exp:channel:entries}
                    </tbody>
                </table> 
            </div>
        </div>   
{/exp:stash:append}

{exp:stash:set name="content"}
    {exp:stash:get name="listings"}
{/exp:stash:set}
```

Answer (score 3):

If your url contains the proper category you can use Low's seg2cat plugin to grab the id

```
category="{segment_xx_category_id}"
```

http://gotolow.com/addons/low-seg2cat

I'm afk from pc, you may have to tweak parse order but I've used this plugin to great affect many times for this purpose.

Comment: Hi stuart. I'm not sure if my current setup would allow me to do that. Right now I'm using the pages module and using a custom url e.g. example.com/us/fl/miami is there a way to do it like so?

Comment: There shouldn't be any problem there. In your example if you wanted the last segment then you'd just use category="{segment_3_category_id}". Where you're using segment_3 to grab the category id. Alternatively you can grab the name and other properties.